# What causes slowdowns when using parallel processes in python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, writefile

I want to create and save the information in the DB as a file using python.

I've tested single process, multiprocess, and even parallel processes using slurm.

I've written code that creates a thousand files per process.

The code is a simple form covered with a loop.

```
fi = open('./file.txt', 'w')
fi.write(infomation)
fi.close
```

The test results for each are as follows.

```
single process : 970 s
multi process : 3730 s
slurm process : almost a day
```

With parallel processes, why do individual processes run slower the more they are used?

Comment: Do you have a system with a parallel file system? If not then reading from and writing to disk are serial operations. While user code (such as yours) might try to execute them in parallel the operating system will serialise disk access - there is only one 'channel' to/from the disk. The figures you report strongly suggest that you have tried to use 4 processes in your `multi process` test and discovered that it takes 4 times as long to serialise 4 files as to serialise 1 file. I don't know what's going on with your `slurm` test.

Comment: What's the point of overwriting the same file in a loop anyway? If your application is I/O-bound, it won't help adding more CPU.

Comment: On most HPC machines there is a shared NFS file system (eg. your home) which is slow and sequential, *not* intended to be used for writing big files by application (since it slow down all users). There is sometimes a local filesystem which is unsafe (eg. /tmp). And often there is a parallel filesystem (eg. scratch data) which scale quite well with the number of process as long as the number is not huge and 1/few processes is used on each node. There are parallel file system API for faster performance on such a PFS (see. MPI).

Comment: Thanks for all replies.

I thought that parallel processes would be more efficient for I/O operations, but I guess I was wrong.

I'll have to find another way to improve performance.